# JCE provider implementation

Tags: java, jce

I need to write a java JCE provider. I have been looking in the net for several days and I could not find solution. Could you please give me some useful informaion.
Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html), but why would you want to do this? Most of the mainstream cryptographic algorithms are implemented already either by Sun or [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html).

Comment: it is only a class assignment

Comment: That's a good reason. Just get a little worried about people implementing custom authentication schemes.

Comment: Both of the Oracle links 404. The latest link (as of 3/2014) appears to be: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to ig's answer, note that the Sun/Oracle JDK requires the JCE provider to be signed by Sun, Oracle or IBM CA. This isn't something you can achieve easily (if at all).

So if it's just for educational purposes, you can follow the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html) for development and use OpenJDK for testing, because it does not require the JCE provider to be signed.
There's also a [Windows OpenJDK version](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/releases) available.